# Woo Commerce - does anyone know how to show Product Categories as main Shop landing page?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, shopping-cart, woocommerce

I read a similar post asking about how to display a top level Shop page with only "Product Categories" - not subcategories, no products.

I have selected the settings on WooCommerce - Settings | Catalog -

x  Show subcategories on category pages

x  Show subcategories on the shop page

x  When showing subcategories, hide products

I still only see my products, not any categories.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Show subcategories on the shop page` should do the trick, have you tried disabling any other plugins and using the default theme?

Some themes & plugins might interfere.

Comment: That's what I had thought too, I have attempted using other Themes and it appears to work so I've notified the Theme creator as they are obviously suppressing the function.  Thanks for your reply.